# How can I use ES2016 decorators in karma?

Tags: karma-runner, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I have set up karma with the `karma-babel-preprocessor`, and `es2015` in the presets.

I'm using decorators in my code but I don't know how to configure karma to accept them. I have been trying for a while unsuccesfully.

Adding `plugins: ['transform-decorators']` to the `babelPreprocessor` options doesn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a currently open issue regarding decorators (which I'm using) and babel.

See these issues in Babel:

[#2645 - Fix Decorators](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2645)

[#2801 - Failed to transform decorators with babel-plugin-transform-decorators@6.0.14](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2801)

[#2727 - Decorators are broken in 6.x](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2727)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801311/webpack-babel-6-es6-decorators for solution.