# Webpack babel 6 ES6 decorators

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, decorator

I've got a project written in ES6 with webpack as my bundler. Most of the transpiling works fine, but when I try to include decorators anywhere, I get this error:

```
Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update.
```

I've looked over the babel issue tracker, and haven't been able to find anything on it there, so I'm assuming I'm using it wrong. My webpack config (the relevant bits):

```
loaders: [
  {
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    query: {
      plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
      presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
    }
  }
]
```

I have no trouble with anything else, arrow functions, destructuring all work fine, this is the only thing that doesn't work.

I know I could always downgrade to babel 5.8 where I had it working a while ago, but if there's any way to get this working in the current version (v6.2.0), it would help.

Comment: I thought since I included the stage-0 preset, that they would get transformed propery. Decorators are part of the stage-1 preset that should include the transform-decorators. As written on the babel website.

Comment: @Pavlin I am thinking whether this could be an issue with the ordering of `presets`.

Comment: I thought it may be that, but I tested it again. Any way I put it I get an error. Apparently the order does matter, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This Babel plugin worked for me:

https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
    // ...
  ]
}
```

or

#### Webpack

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy' ],
    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
  }
}
```

---

### React Native

With `react-native` you must use the `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0` plugin instead.

```
npm i --save babel-preset-react-native-stage-0
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"]
}
```

Please see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36376733/236564) for a complete explanation.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want the plugin enabled only for `development`.

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth. I've update the answer to include `production` as well

Comment: I mean, why put it in an `env` block at all? You can have `plugins` as a sibling of `presets`

Comment: @loganfsmyth, ah, I didn't know that. Updated, thanks.

Comment: Is it on purpose that the order of presets for Webpack is different from Babelrc? (es2015 first instead of react)

Comment: @Micros, no the order doesn't matter. I've update the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: The `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` doesn't work for me. Any updates for 2016?

Comment: @am5255, it still seems to be working for me. Would you mind submitting an issue with the author? https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy/issues

Comment: Was finally able to get this to work. Turns out I had to install `transform-class-properties` as well https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/ and also make sure that the legacy plugin is before the transform class plugin as per the docs in https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Answer (score 41):

After spending 5 minutes on the babeljs slack webchat, I found out that decorators are broken in the current version of babel (v6.2). The only solution seems to be to downgrade to 5.8 at this time.

It would also seem they moved their issue tracker from github to https://phabricator.babeljs.io

I write all this down, since after hours of searching I have found the current documentation very poor and lacking.

Comment: From that issue, a "best-effort with limitations" legacy plugin was made. See readme for limitations: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: I can confirm that the transform decorators legacy is working for me as an interim solution.

Comment: @Pavlin, although your answer may have been correct, the plugin listed below should be the accepted answer for now.

Answer (score 8):

Installing only `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` didn't work for me (I have a configuration using enzyme along with karma). Turns out installing `transform-class-properties`: [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties)  and also making sure that the legacy plugin is before the transform class plugin as per the docs in [transform-decorators-legacy](http://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) finally made it work for me.

I'm also not using a `.babelrc` file, but adding this to my `karma.conf.js` file worked for me:

```
babelPreprocessor: {
  options: {
    presets: ['airbnb', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
    plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
  }
}
```

I also added it to my loaders:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    query: {
      presets: ['airbnb', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
      plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Spend an hour here and there and this things worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

You just need a transform decorators plugin: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/

Comment: Still failed for me w/ that.

Comment: @amcdnl my impression is that the transform decorators plugin is the official one but left unimplemented due to TC39 constraints, in the meantime there is this - https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: @Qiming yup thats what i ended up using and babel official even says that if u dig far enough .. pretty terrible idea on their part imo

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded your project from Babel 6 to Babel 7, then you want to install `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`.

If you want to support legacy decorators as used in Babel 5, you need to configure your `.babelrc` as follows:

```
plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
]
```

Ensure `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` comes before `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in the case that you are making use of the latter.