# React.js Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, react-alt

The technologies that i am using to build my app is React, Web-pack, Babel and AlT(flux implementation)

I'm getting an error when web pack tries to compile my app. Not sure what libraries i am missing.

Could someone please advice ?

```
  ##.babelrc file##
  {"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack babel 6 ES6 decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801311/webpack-babel-6-es6-decorators)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is mostly provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210231/, but I'll recount it here for convenience:

Basically, you TC39 is changing the proposal so Babel is holding off on implementing decorators. If you want the Babel 5 version of decorators (or something similar), you can add this special plugin to Babel - https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy.

Comment: This should be the answer, it worked for me except that it's the commands in the stackoverflow link

```npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy```

and not the ones in the Babel link that worked.

Comment: @RyanVice oops I think I got the link wrong, updated with the right one.

Answer (score 7):

Babel 6 doesn't support decorators yet, see [this issue](http://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645)

The easiest and most stable solution at the moment is use version 5.8.34

Comment: Can we force babel to use it through something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators?

Comment: Why wait? [`babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy)

Comment: The `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` doesn't work for me. Any updates for 2016?

Answer (score 2):

The TC39 is changing the decorator proposal (the 'old' one is implemented in babel 5), so the babel team is waiting them to write the new implementation, or port the old one from babel 5.
The easy way to use decorators now is use babel 5, then wait to TC39 for the new proposal and let the babel team implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after I removed duplicated declaration of

```
"presets: ['es2015', 'react','stage-0'],"
```

in webpack config and .babelrc,it finnaly works.