# How do I get decorators working with babel & webpack?

Tags: javascript, decorator, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I have the following setup:

```
{
  "babel-core": "~5.8.25",
  "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
  "babel-loader": "~5.3.2",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.2.0",
  "eslint": "^1.7.3",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^0.1.0",
  "eslint-loader": "~1.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
  // ...
}
```

webpack:

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'eslint-loader'}],
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel-loader?plugins[]=transform-decorators-legacy'],
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: The plugin "transform-decorators-legacy" didn't export a Plugin instance
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I've since upgraded to Babel 6 and now have the following set up:

```
{
  "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
  "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
  "eslint": "^1.10.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
  "eslint-loader": "^1.2.0",
  "eslint-plugin-angular": "^0.15.0",
  // ...
}
```

and:

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'eslint-loader'}],
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&plugins[]=transform-decorators-legacy'],
    }
  ]
},
```

But get `Parsing error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` referring to the decorator.

Comment: I don't see `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` in your package.json - have you installed it?

Comment: "*get ES6 decorators working*" - no way. Decorators are a feature that is proposed for ES7, not part of ES6.

Comment: @Bergi, my bad... I meant ES7.

Comment: I've since upgraded to babel 6 and now getting an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error, referring to the decorator

Comment: Why not use a .babelrc file, you can specify plugins in there? :)

Comment: Does ESlint throw the parse error or babel?

Comment: @Herku, seems it was eslint and adding `"parser": "babel-eslint",` to .eslintrc fixes it. Next hurdle is getting the karma-babel-preprocessor to play nice as my tests are throwing the same error.

Comment: The current state of decorators is a bit frustrating. One way could be to avoid decorators until there is progress in the draft...

Answer (score 2):

After some searching and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801311/webpack-babel-6-es6-decorators), I was able to get it working without using a `.babelrc` file.

### Install [`transform-decorators-legacy`](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy)

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`

### Include the plugin in `webpack.config.js`

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
      presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
    }
  }
]
```