# React issue - @ is an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I'm trying to implement react-keydown which can be found here: https://github.com/glortho/react-keydown using the following code example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import keydown, { Keys } from 'react-keydown';

class MethodDecoratorExample extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      hello: false
    };
  }

  @keydown( 'enter' )
  toggleHello() {
    this.setState( { hello: !this.state.hello } );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Method Decorator Example</h3>
        <div>Press the <strong>enter</strong> key to toggle hello.</div>
        { this.state.hello &&
          <h1>Enter is key code {Keys.enter}!</h1>
        }
        <div>And click again outside box to see scoping.</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try this I get an unexpected token error on the @. I have no clue how to solve this.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you built it with webpack or similar tools? I'm not sure, but looking at their package.json, you have decorators etc. which I think has to be processed to run on the browser.

Comment: @cbll I'm using webpack - am I missing something in there?

Answer (score 4):

Babel 6 no longer supports ES decorator syntax [out of the box](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) so you need to install the `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` plugin.

### Install babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

### Add the plugin in your `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

### or

add the loader directly in your `webpack.config.js`

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy' ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [How do I get decorators working with babel & webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268827/how-do-i-get-decorators-working-with-babel-webpack)

Thanks to @cbll for mentioning decorators, because I did not know that that is the correct term. Helped me with searching for solutions