# Using react-hot-loader with Babel 6

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, react-hot-loader

I have upgraded to Babel 6 and trying to make it working with react-hot-loader, in the webpack.config file, I have this:

```
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
    }
```

The config above gives this error:

```
Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list"
```

Webpack is probably confused whether if the query is for `react-hot-loader` or `babel`.

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an excerpt of the `webpack.config.js` file I use:

```
loaders: [{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0']
}
```

As you can see the presets for babel can be specified directly in the `loaders` section.

Comment: Thanks, it works! What about plugins? I am running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801311/webpack-babel-6-es6-decorators/34210231#34210231

Comment: Nevermind, I got it: `loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?cacheDirectory,presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,plugins[]=transform-decorators-legacy'],`

Comment: For complicated query, use [`webpack-combine-loaders`](https://github.com/jsdf/webpack-combine-loaders).