# New react-native app has 'TypeError: babelHelpers.typeof is not a function' [iOS]

Tags: ios, react-native, babeljs

A new project created with the latest version of react-native throws javascript error while running(/debugging). Tested this on simulator.

```
[fatal][tid:main] TypeError: babelHelpers.typeof is not a function. (In 'babelHelpers.typeof(target)', 'babelHelpers.typeof' is undefined)
```

Installed the react-native client today & created the app using

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

App version:

```
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.20.0
node version: v5.6.0
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. Some people have had success with these methods...I have not https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5747

Comment: I had `react-native-cli` installed under my home folder using a `.npmrc` with a custom `prefix=/`. I reinstalled the `react-native-cli` after removing this option.  New projects created with the new client started working. I still don't know what the real problem is.

Comment: Are you using a .babelrc file ? If yes, can you show us its content ?

Comment: I was not using a `.bablerc`. It is a clean project created by running `react-native init`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the react-native init and running project :(

Comment: I've also run into this, and even after fixing it once via the github issue referenced by @ken4z, it came back and the same fix did not work. This hints at a deeper flaw in the packager code related to its dependencies and caching. Quite frustrating since the last time it popped up for me, I hadn't changed anything (git branch was clean from last known working config...).

Answer (score 30):

Here's a comment explaining the issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4844#issuecomment-204035720

To summarize:

Babel presets `'stage-0'` through `'stage-3'` contain `'async-to-generator'`, which is not not necessary for react-native itself.

The solution is to use the unofficial babel preset `'react-native-stage-0'`

#### Example:

```
npm install babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 --save-dev
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
}
```

or with decorator support

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"]
}
```

**Empty cache and Restart**

```
watchman watch-del-all

./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 6):

Solved adding babel stage-1 and react-native preset's to .babelrc in the project's root folder.

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-1", "react-native"],
}
```

More details here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5747

Comment: This didn't work for me.  It seems that people are sometimes able to strike the right sequence of buttons to get it to work temporarily, but not consistently.  It seems there is something more core going on.

Comment: This preset results here in an infinite loop of "loading from localhost:8081"... Am i the only one?

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem, I renamed a .babelrc file in a parent directory, then ran `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --reset-cache`

Comment: Simply running with `--reset-cache` solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that if there is a `.babelrc` in a parent directory to your app, the packager will read that and it will cause this exact error. One way around it is to add a `.babelrc` file in your project:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated to the newly released `react-native@0.21` and the issue went away.  I am not sure if this means the root issue has been resolved since I have seen intermittent success with other "fixes".

Answer (score 0):

Double check your import path/file names as they are **case sensitive**

Answer (score 0):

It's usually due to a 3rd party npm dependency that has .babelrc or babel es2015 preset specified in it's package.json.

There's a fix in place: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11093