# Legacy Decorators: Extend last argument of a function with props and invoke it

Tags: javascript, decorator, babeljs

Am using [legacy decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) for decorating a function in such a way that all props given to that decorator will be applied to the last **optional** argument of the function. 
Decorator code:

```
export function dec(props){
  return (target, property, descriptor) => {
    //Note: WIP!! Does not work for all scenarios!
    var fn = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function () {
      if(!arguments.length) return fn.apply(this,new Array(props));
      let [last, ...first] = [...arguments].reverse();
      last = Object.assign(last, props);
      return fn.apply(this, [...([...first].reverse()), last]);
    };
};
```

}

Base API definition :

```
funcA ( data, opts = {}) { /*funcA body*/ }
funcB ( id, data, opts = {}) { /*funcB body*/ }
funcB ( opts = {}) { /*funcC body*/ }
```

Wrapper class function definitions:

```
 @({ k1: 'v1'})
 wrapFuncA(data, opts = {} /*optional*/){
    return this.funcA(id, opts);
 }

 @({ k1: 'v1'})
 wrapFuncB(id, data, opts = {} /*optional*/){
    return this.funcB(id, data, opts);
 }

 @({ k1: 'v1'})
 wrapFuncC(opts = {} /*optional*/){
    return this.funcC(opts);
 }
```

Invocation use cases:

1. `wrapFuncA(1);                      // will invoke: funcA(1,{ k1: 'v1'})`
2. `wrapFuncB(1, dObj, {k2: 'v2'});    // will invoke: funcB(1, dObj, { k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2'})`
3. `wrapFuncB(1, dObj);                // will invoke: funcB(1, dObj, { k1: 'v1'})`
4. `wrapFuncC({k3:'v3'});              // will invoke: funcC({ k1: 'v1'},{ k3: 'v3'})`

The general logic would be: Take the last argument and extend it with decorator props. However, because of the requirement of last argument being optional, this will fail in case of 3 above.

Any suggestion on how to solve this would he appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ES6 has no decorators! It's a Babel plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack babel 6 ES6 decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801311/webpack-babel-6-es6-decorators)